# Insert data from Oracle into a DataGridView with existing column names

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

I'm about to write an application with WinForm that retrieves data from Oracle and inserts it into a DataGridView. The special thing: The DataGridView already has column names. When clicking the button, the data should be loaded in the corresponding column. I want the user to see the column names in DataGridView before the data including column names are loaded.

How can I do that or in other words how can I assign the columns in Oracle to the columns in the DataGridView. THANKS

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try

        {

            string ConString = "Data Source= DWH;User Id=readonly;Password=*******;";

            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES", con);
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                oda.Fill(data);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, instead of setting names for columns in datagridview you can set name from the query.

Example :

```
Select fname as 'Full Name', lname as 'Last name',dob as 'Date of Birth'
From employeeDetails
```

Then the column names of the datagridview will be names that you specify in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the DataGridView's data source to a `BindingSource` instance.  Bind the BindingSource's datasource to a `List<SomeType>`.  The `SomeType` class should have all the public properties you want to display.  If there are properties you don't want to display, you can remove them from the grid with a `[Browsable(false)]` attribute on the property.  If you want to rename a field like `fname` to `Full Name`, use a `[DisplayName]` attribute on the property.

If you do that after the data grid view is initialized, but before it is displayed, it will initially display with the column names and no rows.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer I changed the options  auto column generated to false